# QWebEngineView can't run

Tags: qt

Windows 10 and Qt Creator MSVC2015_64,I compile and run an example of QWebEngineView. just like this:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWebEngineView>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWebEngineView *view = new QWebEngineView();
    view->load(QUrl("http://qt-project.org/"));
    view->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

but this code can not show the view,it give some message:

```
[2460:3120:0718/170222.823:INFO:dxva_video_decode_accelerator_win.cc(1120)] mf.dll is required for hardware video decoding
[2460:3120:0718/170222.823:INFO:dxva_video_decode_accelerator_win.cc(1120)] mf.dll is required for hardware video decoding
[2460:3120:0718/170223.229:ERROR:gl_context_wgl.cc(78)] Could not share GL contexts.
[2460:3120:0718/170223.229:ERROR:gl_context_wgl.cc(78)] Could not share GL contexts.
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Which Windows Version are you running?

The mf.dll is part of Windows 6/7/8/10 (and therefore not run on Windows XP). If you are running Windows XP, you have to confile Qt with the configure option "-target xp" for option "-no-wmf-backend" to be compatible with Windows XP.

If you are running a modern version,then try it by installing [Windows Live Essentials](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/18614/windows-essentials#t1=overview) and the [Media Feature Package](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=53356)